# Restkit basic url response

Tags: ios, json, web-services, afnetworking, restkit

I am learning Rest-kit. i am trying to parse this url https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses?fields=language,shortDescription

I have created one Courses class.

```
@interface Courses : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;

@end
```

and in viewcontroller i have wrote below code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self configureRestKit];
    [self loadCourses];
}

- (void)configureRestKit
{

    //  https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/courses?fields=language,shortDescription

    // initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.coursera.org"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    // initialize RestKit
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

    // setup object mappings
    RKObjectMapping *courseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Courses class]];
    [courseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"name":@"name"
                                                       }];
    // register mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:courseMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:@"/api/catalog.v1/courses?fields=language,shortDescription" keyPath:@"elements" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)loadCourses
{
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/catalog.v1/courses?fields=language,shortDescription" parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"%@", mappingResult.array);

    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"What do you mean by 'there is no Courses?': %@", error);
    }];
}
```

**ERROR :_Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded."**
I am not getting response in success block. Please correct me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please describe an error, and what efforts you've made to debug it.

Comment: @HotLicks- Sorry, Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add your query parameters to the path pattern on the response descriptor, and set them as parameters on the request:

```
pathPattern:@"/api/catalog.v1/courses"
```

generally I would also say that `/api/catalog.v1/` should be part of the base URL so you would have:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.coursera.org/api/catalog.v1/"];
...
... pathPattern:@"courses" ...
...
... getObjectsAtPath:@"courses" parameters:@{ @"fields" : @"language,shortDescription" } ...
```